# Scala parameterized methods and arithmetic operations

Tags: scala

I am trying to get a simple piece of functionality to work where I have a List of Lists and I want to do some mathematical operations on the data (-, + , *, /).  I want the method to take any of the following types (Int, Float, Double).

here is what I have tried:

```
def doSomething[T](data: List[T]){
 data reduceLeft(_ / _)
}
```

the following is displayed: value / is not a member of type parameter T.

How do I get this to work for the AnyVal types (Double, Int, Float)?

Update I tried implementing the suggestion in the following code:

```
def dot[T](l: List[List[T]])(implicit num: Numeric[T]) = 
{

    for (row <- data)
        yield for(col <- l)
            yield row zip col map {a => num.times(a._1 , a._2)}   reduceLeft (_+_)
```

and get the error: type mismatch;  found   : a._1.type (with underlying type T)  required: T

Is there any way to get around that?

Comment: what is `data` in your first `for` ?

Comment: sorry data is a List[List[T]].

Comment: i figured out one way to do this was to have it contained within a parameterized class.  But, I am still wondering why the above doesn't work?  Especially if I wanted to use this method as a Function Object.

Comment: It seems it doesn't work because `times` requires both arguments to be of the same type T, in this case there is no ensurance that `data`'s underlying type T and `dot`'s type T are the same type. If you want to avoid parameterized class, try passing to function `data` parameter as well

Comment: for example 
`def dot[T](data: List[List[T]])(l: List[List[T]])(implicit num: Numeric[T]) = ...`, then use `dot(data) _`

Comment: Very nice!  Thanks for the example.

Comment: Interesting, type bounds on `T` like `<% Double` or `<: Numeric[T]` do not work immediately, not even for `+`. Wonder why.

Comment: btw, you may also try
`implicit val data = List(List(1, 2, 3))`;

`def dot[T](l: List[List[T]])(implicit num: Numeric[T], data: List[List[T]]) = for (row <- data) yield for(col <- l) yield row zip col map {a => num.times(a._1 , a._2)} reduceLeft (num.plus(_,_))`

Answer (score 9):

For division:

```
def foo[T](l: List[T])(implicit num: Numeric[T]) = num match{
     case i: Integral[_] => l reduceLeft (i.quot(_, _))
     case fr: Fractional[_] => l reduceLeft (fr.div(_, _))}
```

For +, - and * it's easier (`plus`, `minus`, `times` respectively):

```
def foo[T](l: List[T])(implicit num: Numeric[T]) = l reduceLeft (num.plus(_, _))
```

Comment: It should be mentioned that what you see here is often called the "(Implicit) Type Class Pattern". See e.g. http://java.dzone.com/articles/scala-implicits-type-classes

Comment: Now the trouble appears to be with using tuple values with Numeric.  I have updated my example to show the issue.